# No column was specified for Column 1 of C1

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, sql-server-2019

i need help please i have been stuck on this for 3 days now , i have googled endlessly but i cant seem to fix this, can someone please help me fix this and explain what i did wrong?

i keep getting the No Column was specified for C1 error and when i try to execute it i keep getting

*Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Procedure XXX, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 7]
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.*

```
SELECT TOP 1 @DataIndex = DataIndex,
                 @ChannelDescription = Description,
                 @UserConfigurationData = UserConfigurationData
    FROM DevicesCW WHERE Id = @DTSourceRecId
    
        
    SELECT @DataIndex DataIndex,Column_Id ChannelID, value ChannelName INTO #CName FROM dbo.[fn_split_string_to_column] (@ChannelDescription,@delimiter)
    SELECT @DataIndex DataIndex,Column_Id ChannelID, value ChannelNumber INTO #CNumber FROM dbo.[fn_split_string_to_column] (@UserConfigurationData,@delimiter);
    
    --Test Code--
    --Channel 1
    With C1 AS (SELECT  @ReoDeviceId,CN.ChannelNumber,C.ChannelID,D.Totaliser1Units TotaliserUnits, C.ChannelName, 'CW', @DTSourceRecId,'B', C.ChannelName,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY @DTSourceRecId)
            FROM DevicesCW D
                JOIN #CName C
                    ON D.DataIndex = C.DataIndex AND C.ChannelID = 1
                JOIN #CNumber CN
                    ON D.DataIndex = C.DataIndex AND C.ChannelID = 1
                LEFT JOIN ReoDeviceMeter RDM
                    ON D.DataIndex = RDM.DeviceIndex AND RDM.ChannelNumber = 1
            WHERE D.Id = @DTSourceRecId AND RDM.ReoMeterId IS NULL)
    INSERT INTO ReoMeter(ReoDeviceId, MeterNumber, ChannelNumber, ChanUnitOfMeasure, Description, DtSource, DtSourceRecId, MeterType, SourceDescription)
    SELECT @ReoDeviceId,ChannelNumber,ChannelID,TotaliserUnits,ChannelName,'CW',@DTSourceRecId,'B',ChannelName

    FROM C1
    WHERE RN = 1
    Group BY @ReoDeviceId,ChannelNumber,ChannelID,TotaliserUnits,ChannelName,'CW',@DTSourceRecId,'B',ChannelName


    -- Test Code---
```

I am trying to go the above route to resolve an issue where the blow code duplicates the data in the database for each Channel. if i have 2 channels it inserts the data 2 times for CH1 and CH2 instead of just inserting the data for each Channel

```
--Channel1
    INSERT INTO ReoMeter(ReoDeviceId, MeterNumber, ChannelNumber, ChanUnitOfMeasure, Description, DtSource, DtSourceRecId, MeterType, SourceDescription)
    SELECT  @ReoDeviceId,CN.ChannelNumber,C.ChannelID,D.Totaliser1Units, C.ChannelName, 'CW', @DTSourceRecId,'B', C.ChannelName
    FROM DevicesCW D
        JOIN #CName C
            ON D.DataIndex = C.DataIndex AND C.ChannelID = 1
        JOIN #CNumber CN
            ON D.DataIndex = C.DataIndex AND C.ChannelID = 1
        LEFT JOIN ReoDeviceMeter RDM
            ON D.DataIndex = RDM.DeviceIndex AND RDM.ChannelNumber = 1
    WHERE D.Id = @DTSourceRecId AND RDM.ReoMeterId IS NULL

    --Channel2
    INSERT INTO ReoMeter(ReoDeviceId, MeterNumber, ChannelNumber, ChanUnitOfMeasure, Description, DtSource, DtSourceRecId, MeterType, SourceDescription)
    SELECT  @ReoDeviceId,CN.ChannelNumber,C.ChannelID,D.Totaliser2Units, C.ChannelName, 'CW', @DTSourceRecId, 'B', C.ChannelName
    FROM DevicesCW D
        JOIN #CName C
            ON D.DataIndex = C.DataIndex AND C.ChannelID = 2
        JOIN #CNumber CN
            ON D.DataIndex = C.DataIndex AND C.ChannelID = 2
        LEFT JOIN ReoDeviceMeter RDM
            ON D.DataIndex = RDM.DeviceIndex AND RDM.ChannelNumber = 2
    WHERE D.Id = @DTSourceRecId AND RDM.ReoMeterId IS NULL
```

Comment: The above code is product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: you need to assign alias to those expression in your CTE `C1`

Comment: MSSQL Server 2019  with SQL Server Management Studio V18.9.2

Comment: I know i need to assign alias to the expression that much i picked up from searching stack overflow, i just dont know how or where i need to assign it i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. `SELECT  @ReoDeviceId,CN.ChannelNumber`. Where is the name/alias for the column where the value is that of the variable/parameter `@ReoDeviceId`? There are other columns with the same problem too.

Comment: There's a bunch of weird things going on in your code: `fn_split_string_to_column` why don't you just use `STRING_SPLIT`? Why the need for temp tables, just use standard joins. `PARTITION BY @DTSourceRecId` is non-deterministic and could give different results each time. `ChannelID = 1` and `ChannelID = 2` could be merged `ChannelID IN (1, 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Give Aleas for the all columns of C1 to fix the issue.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @DataIndex = dataindex,
             @ChannelDescription = description,
             @UserConfigurationData = userconfigurationdata
FROM   devicescw
WHERE  id = @DTSourceRecId

SELECT @DataIndex DataIndex,
       column_id  ChannelID,
       value      ChannelName
INTO   #cname
FROM   dbo.[Fn_split_string_to_column] (@ChannelDescription, @delimiter)

SELECT @DataIndex DataIndex,
       column_id  ChannelID,
       value      ChannelNumber
INTO   #cnumber
FROM   dbo.[Fn_split_string_to_column] (@UserConfigurationData, @delimiter);

--Test Code--
--Channel 1
WITH c1
     AS (SELECT @ReoDeviceId      AS ReoDeviceId,
                CN.channelnumber,
                C.channelid,
                D.totaliser1units TotaliserUnits,
                C.channelname,
                'CW'              AS CW,
                @DTSourceRecId    AS DTSourceRecId,
                'B'               AS B,
                C.channelname,
                RN = Row_number()
                       OVER(
                         partition BY @DTSourceRecId)
         FROM   devicescw D
                JOIN #cname C
                  ON D.dataindex = C.dataindex
                     AND C.channelid = 1
                JOIN #cnumber CN
                  ON D.dataindex = C.dataindex
                     AND C.channelid = 1
                LEFT JOIN reodevicemeter RDM
                       ON D.dataindex = RDM.deviceindex
                          AND RDM.channelnumber = 1
         WHERE  D.id = @DTSourceRecId
                AND RDM.reometerid IS NULL)
INSERT INTO reometer
            (reodeviceid,
             meternumber,
             channelnumber,
             chanunitofmeasure,
             description,
             dtsource,
             dtsourcerecid,
             metertype,
             sourcedescription)
SELECT reodeviceid,
       channelnumber,
       channelid,
       totaliserunits,
       channelname,
       cw,
       dtsourcerecid,
       b,
       channelname
FROM   c1
WHERE  rn = 1
GROUP  BY reodeviceid,
          channelnumber,
          channelid,
          totaliserunits,
          channelname,
          cw,
          dtsourcerecid,
          b,
          channelname
```

Comment: There are other columns without names (aliases) too in the CTE's definition.

Comment: Why did you add a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation?

Comment: Just copy paste of the above code with issue identification and group by is used to avoid duplications which is mentioned in the second part of question.

Comment: Thank you, Yes i now have error on col 6 so do i need to supply aliases for each of the columns

Comment: Yes, sure please accept the answer and give upvote if it had helped you..

Comment: Guys and Galls i have very little experience with SQL i am trying to learn and fix this issue at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for Helping i know understand where i when wrong with the Aliases. i still have the other error ```The function 'Row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.``` to fix

Comment: "group by is used to avoid duplications "* Why not `SELECT DISTINCT`? The `GROUP BY` clause is for when you are aggregating; there's no aggregation here.

Comment: i will try the ```SELECT DISTINCT``` as well thank you for all the help